# Adverb-Position vor Reflexivpronomen?

Tags: verb

Wieso nutzen wir Adverbiale eher nach (rechts) dem Reflexivpronomen, und vermeiden die Stellung davor?

> Ich wasche mein Auto oft.

Ist ebenso natürlich wie

> Ich wasche oft mein Auto.

Nutzen wir aber ein Reflexivpronomen...

> Ich wasche mich oft.

...vermeiden wir eher die Position vor dem Reflexivpronomen:

> Ich wasche **oft mich**.

Wie kommt es dazu? Ist diese Beobachtung für alle reflexiv verwendeten Verben und alle Reflexivpronomen die wir mit ihnen nutzen gültig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das hängt damit zusammen, dass Nomen-Akkusativobjekte und Pronomen-Akkusativobjekte im Satz an einer unterschiedlichen Stelle einsortiert werden. Vergleiche mal

> Ich wasche am Samstag mein Auto.

> Ich wasche es am Samstag.

Es hat also nichts mit der Reflexivität zu tun.

Die zugrundeliegende Logik ist, dass bereits zuvor erwähnte Dinge im deutschen Satz früher stehen als neue Informationen, und Pronomen verweisen naturgemäß auf etwas, was zuvor erwähnt wurde. In der Praxis wirkt sich das aber meist nur auf das Thema und das Akkusativobjekt aus.

Die übliche Reihenfolge der Satzglieder ist

1. Thema deiner Wahl (Vorfeld — nur im Hauptsatz)
2. V2-Verb (nur im Hauptsatz)
3. Subjekt
4. Pronomen-Akkusativobjekt
5. Dativobjekt
6. Adverbial der Zeit
7. Adverbial des Grundes
8. Adverbial der Art und Weise
9. Adverbial des Ortes (nicht der Richtung!)
10. Nomen-Akkusativobjekt
11. Adverbial der Richtung oder Präpositionalobjekt
12. Prädikat-Verben
13. Adverbial deiner Wahl oder Vergleich (Nachfeld)

Comment: Danke schön für diese Antwort!

Answer (score 2):

Die verschiedenen Positionen des Adverbs drücken eine unterschiedliche Betonung aus, das Reflexivpronomen ist nicht massgebend.

Nach dem Verb betont das Adverb *oft* die Häufigkeit: *Ich wasche mein Auto oft, öfter als andere.* Vor dem Adverb betont es die Regelmässigkeit: *Ich wasche oft mein Auto samstags, deshalb sind die Pfützen manchmal sonntags noch sichtbar.*

Ähnlich geht es im zweiten Beispiel: *Ich wasche mich oft, weil ich mich gern sauber fühle,* gegenüber *Ich wasche oft mich selbst, wechsele aber nicht jedesmal meine Kleidung.*